# Casting from type to object back to type returns null

Tags: c#, reporting-services, casting, parameter-passing

I have an object `RS2005.ParameterValue[] parameters`. I declare its labels,names and values. Then I pass it to another function, lets call it A.
When I try to assign it to a temp variable `temp` of type RS2005.ParameterValue[] inside function A, It returns null, even though the object is not empty (according to the debugger). This function worked fine a few builds ago, but at some point recently it stopped working, I'm wondering if it might have something to do with change of Visual Studio version to 2015?

Original function

```
RS2005.ParameterValue[] parameters = new RS2005.ParameterValue[5];
parameters[0] = new RS2005.ParameterValue();
parameters[0].Label = "a";
parameters[0].Name = "a";
parameters[0].Value = "AA";
.....

frontPageBytes = Functions.functionA(parameters);
```

FunctionA

```
 public static byte[] functionA(object parameters)
    {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        RS2005.ReportExecutionService rsExec = new RS2005.ReportExecutionService();
        rsExec.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(RSServerUserLogin, RSServerUserPassword, RSServerUserDomain);
        rsExec.Url = RSServerWSURI;
        string deviceInfo = string.Format(@"<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>{0}</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>", "PDF");

        RS2005.ExecutionInfo ei = rsExec.LoadReport(rdlPath, null);
        RS2005.ParameterValue[] temp = parameters as RS2005.ParameterValue[];  <---------- This temp is null

        rsExec.SetExecutionParameters(parameters as RS2005.ParameterValue[], "en-us"); <---------- this throws an exception because parameters is null
        ....
}
```

Comment: "even though the object is not empty " which object? `parameters` inside the `functionA` ? up to now I cannot reproduce your problem

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but why not change the type of functionA to `public static byte[] functionA(RS2005.ParameterValue[] parameters)` and get the assistance of compile time type safety? Going through `object` and back again seems an unnecessary risk.

Comment: @StuartLC Or use a direct cast instead of the as-cast.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. What I did not mention in the question, is that function A, and the original function were in different projects. That's connected to the reason why I had to cast to `object` and then back to RS20005.ParameterValue[].

What I did not notice is that the project A and project B had slightly different versions of Report Viewer. When I cast using `as`, C# tried to save me by returning null, which made me unable to find the error. Only after casting directly did i find the cause of the problem.